# Dynamics Nav - How to highlight a row in a FactBox that contains a list

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

Relatively new to C/AL development. We have a FactBox page that contains a repeater with a Temporary table page source. The number of lines in the FactBox matches the number of lines in the parent page. The temporary records in the FactBox are accumulated one at a time based on a call from the parent page OnAfterGetRecord trigger. They are loaded into the FactBox based on a call from the parent page OnAfterGetCurrRecord trigger.

1a. For purposes of discussion, lets say there are 10 records in the parent page and in the FactBox page. How do I highlight the matching row in the FactBox when the user selects a given row in the parent page (e.g. they select row 3, I want to highlight row 3 in the FactBox)?

1b. How do I highlight multiple rows if the user selects multiple rows with Shift+Click or Ctrl+Click?

In the case of 1a above, OnAfterGetRecord is fired in the parent page with a filter equal to the key. In the second case, OnAfterGetRecord is fired in the parent page for each record selected by the user with a filter equal to 'Marked: Yes'. If I try to use Mark in the FactBox page, it filters the records so that only the selected ones are displayed in the FactBox, which is not what I want.

We are using 2013R2, although I would be interested in answers for other versions as well.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and/or suggestions.

PS. The FactBox is kind of a summary at a glance idea for each list row contained in the parent page. It contains a handful of temporary table fields that are populated from the parent page row primary key when the parent page OnAfterGetRecord and OnAfterGetCurrRecord triggers are fired. There is a 1 to 1 relationship between parent page lines and FactBox lines.

Basically, instead of having the FactBox oriented vertically displaying data only for the active parent page row, we transposed the FactBox vertical fields into a horizontal row of fields and display one row of FactBox data for each row of parent page data. The FactBox resyncs when the user sorts the parent page by clicking on the headers, etc.

Comment: @Mak Sim Sorry for the lack of clarity in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can’t even imagine your business case. Maybe if you spill it you will get a better advice.

Short answer for what you’re asking is.. you can’t. And you don’t want to. This is a factbox. It should provide extended information about line which you don’t want to put into repeater or fasttab because it is from related table. Hence the limitations.

And one more thing. Nav is very limited in terms of different fancy events and triggers. The only way to make it more advance is to write your own visual plugin which will replace most of the page’s interface. There you can do whatever JS (for example) allows you to do.